# Write a method signature including the class name for documentation

Tags: objective-c, documentation

Is there a language standard (or common practice) for describing an Objective-C method *with the class name included*?

For example, let's say I have the following pseudocode:

```
class Foo
{
  void bar(int i);
}
```

and I want to write some documentation for it.

If this were Java, I would refer to the method as `Foo.bar()`.  If it were C++, I would use `Foo::bar`.  What is the right way to do this for Objective-C?

I know that I can use `-(void) bar:(int)i`, but this does not include the class (or protocol) name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually it's `-[Foo bar:]`. There may be a plus sign instead of minus when the method is a class method.