# Objective-C Methods Referencing

Tags: objective-c, documentation, selector, method-names

I know how to write selector names in Objective-C like `mergeThis:withThat:`, but can somebody tell me, how can I reference (e.g. in documentation, text or commit message) that a method belongs to a class and is either an instance method or a class method?

In Ruby I would write `String#reverse` for instance methods or `File::exists?(file_name)` for class methods. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736120/why-are-methods-in-ruby-documentation-preceded-by-a-hash-sign).

Is there a standardized way or a convention to do so in Objective-C?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Write a method signature including the class name for documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10421265/write-a-method-signature-including-the-class-name-for-documentation)

Comment: Sorry, I have searched for it, but I did not found it.

Comment: No need to apologize. Unless there's more than a few duplicates, it can be hard to find the original.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Objective-C you'd write something like this for instance method:

```
-[MyClass myMethodWithArg:andAnotherArg:]
```

and this for class method:

```
+[MyClass staticMethodWithArg:andAnotherArg:]
```

**update to comment**

I am using `NSLog`'s `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` output format (per [Zarra Studio's coding guidelines](http://www.cimgf.com/zds-code-style-guide/)) which gives that kind of output. Apple's documentation provides following format, but it's class-context dependent:

[image]

Comment: Is it just your convention or is it based on some documentation? Could you please post a reference?

Comment: Thanks for your update! The format of Apple's documentation is useless for me due to the class-context dependency. But the _pretty function_ format solves my problem. I would like to wait for another answers and if nobody offers a better solution, I will take yours.

Answer (score 0):

when you declare methods in .h of a class, you give a symbol in front of every method..

`-` negative symbol means that it is an instance method

`+` positive symbol means that it is an class method

you can call a class method like this...

```
[ClassName yourMethod];
```

EDIT:

I am not exactly sure what you are asking as I have no idea about Ruby but I think this answer should help you(I guess you are looking if a class contains certain method) https://stackoverflow.com/a/1135522/919545

Comment: I know this, of course. :-) My question is how to write it out of the code. How can I express that a method belongs to a class and what type is it?

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, but my question has nothing to do with coding. I want to write **in a text** that a class has a method with a name and a specific type (instance/class).